# Laptop Battery/AC Indicator Lag

Tags: 16.04, power-management, indicator, battery

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop (Aspire 4755G). The laptop/AC indicator in Unity works but there is about a minute's worth of lag between changes. There was no such problem in earlier versions of Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Note:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online
```

works as expected.

Comment: Are you talking about a lag in the AC indicator LED on your laptop?

Comment: No I mean in Unity.

Comment: The power display tends to have a lag but it does tell you how long ago the information was refreshed.

Comment: I'm voting this question closed because it's normal behavior. But upvoting the question to give you more points. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a new feature request.

Comment: But this was never a problem in earlier versions of Ubuntu, I only noticed after switching to 16.04

Comment: Unless there is a configuration that can be changed your question then becomes a new feature request or a bug report which also get closed.... Sorry that's just the way I see it :( Hopefully someone comes along and recommends another option for you :)